# How do i click a Button inside a Table using Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, selenium

```
<table _ngcontent-c19="" class="table">
  <tbody _ngcontent-c19="">
    <tr _ngcontent-c19=""><!---->
      <td _ngcontent-c19="" class="ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-c19="" class="span3" style="height: auto;">
          <div _ngcontent-c19="" class="text-center" style="visibility: visible;">
            <button _ngcontent-c19="" class="b1" type="submit">Click This</button>
          </div><!---->
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to click a button inside a table using SELENIUM.

The Code I've Written is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(getText(),'Click This')]").click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('b1').click()
```

they both throw an Element not Found Exception

Comment: what is the website

Comment: you can also use the developer tab to find the xpath to the button. Then you can use the same logic you have with .click()

Comment: www.irctc.co.in
You will have to login and enter a few details to find the table i'm speaking about

Comment: I've tried using xpath...the same exception is thrown

Comment: I would use the developer tab, find the button and you can right click in chrome at least to "find x-path", then you can put that xpath in the driver.find_element_by_xpath(THIS IS THE XPATH).click()

Comment: Have you tried by CSS selector ?

Comment: //*[@id="ui-panel-4-content"]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[3]/button
as the xpath argument?
will this work?

Comment: CSS Selectors also gave me the same....I'm beginning to doubt if it's really accesible?!

Comment: @cruisepandey if it is a matter of timing for the button to appear, could he not do a simple time.sleep(xx) ?

Comment: @dataviews : well `time.sleep(time)` is worst case of explicit wait , WebDriverWait is good approach here and every where you want to wait. Cause time.sleep will set the exact time to wait but webdriver will check DOM in every 500 ms whether element is available or not , if it is available then it would return you immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this **xpath** :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Click This') and @class='b1']"))).click()
```

Note that you will have to import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your code runs faster than your browser that's why you need to tell him to wait until the element is visible and clickable.

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Click This']"))
button.click()
```

Comment: is 10 max timeout?

Comment: No, you can configure your timeout as you want